# Unable to filter view using query string parameter

Tags: 2013, list-view, query-string

I have two lists one is tasks list and the other is document library.

In Tasks list I have created one `lookup` column of the document library i.e. document is shown with tasks.

I have created view using UI of Tasks list which filters the tasks by the document id provided in the Query string parameter. To do so, I edited the view in the SharePoint designer.

My xml for view is as below which appears in the SPDesigner:

```
 <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortdir" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_sortfield" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_startposition" Location="Postback" DefaultValue=""/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_firstrow" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
    <ParameterBinding Name="OpenMenuKeyAccessible" Location="Resource(wss,OpenMenuKeyAccessible)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="open_menu" Location="Resource(wss,open_menu)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="select_deselect_all" Location="Resource(wss,select_deselect_all)" />
    <ParameterBinding Name="idPresEnabled" Location="Resource(wss,idPresEnabled)" /> <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
   <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(core,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
   <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
   <ParameterBinding Name="MoreAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,moreItemsParen)" />
   <ParameterBinding Name="ID" Location="QueryString(ID)" DefaultValue="0"/>
</ParameterBindings>
<View Name="{05EFB3E3-3F47-4782-A2A2-55B5E05483CB}" MobileView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="DocumentView" Url="/sites/pub-3105/Lists/Tasks/DocumentView.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/issuelst.png?rev=23" >
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Document" LookupId="TRUE"/>
                <Value Type="Lookup">{ID}</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Where></Query>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name="Checkmark"/>
        <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/>
        <FieldRef Name="DueDate"/>
        <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
        <FieldRef Name="Document"/>
    </ViewFields>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <Aggregations Value="Off"/><JSLink>hierarchytaskslist.js</JSLink>
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink><Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
</View>
```

But when I go to the view in the task list and provide the parameter like : [url]?ID=1 I am not getting the items filtered by the document id, though there are 2 items in the list which has given the lookup value to the same document id in the query string parameter.

The filtered view is going to be placed in the ViewForm of document library to display the relevant tasks of the document.

What am I missing?

Comment: `ID` might be an internal parameter name, try using some other name for the parameter like `DocumentId` or `CustomFilterId` etc.

Comment: Thanks for replying but the actual requirement is I will place this view in the ViewForm of Document library and the as per the item viewed from the document library the relevant tasks will be displayed.

Is there better way other than this to achieve this? as per your view?

Comment: I'm just guessing, can you try using some other variable for the QueryString parameter and check if it works..

Comment: You are right sir, but when the user will select particular document and will click on the View Property and the view property form has the query string parameter ID. That ID I want to use in the filter. As I will not be able to provide my custom query string parameter when the Display Form of document library will be opened.

Comment: Can you please try the answer below

Answer (score 1):

The ID parameter name should be already in use, try following..

Replace

`<ParameterBinding Name="ID" Location="QueryString(ID)" DefaultValue="0"/>`

With

`<ParameterBinding Name="DocumentId" Location="QueryString(ID)" DefaultValue="0"/>`

And then simply replace

`<FieldRef Name="Document" LookupId="TRUE"/>
<Value Type="Lookup">{ID}</Value>`

With

`<FieldRef Name="Document" LookupId="TRUE"/>
<Value Type="Lookup">{DocumentId}</Value>`

Comment: I tried the way you suggested but not working. :-(

Comment: Any ideas why it is not working?

Comment: Nop I'm out of ideas, let someone else jump in..

Answer (score 0):

Check is your changes are realy saved to view - reopen view in sharepoint designer.
Will the task list be filtered if your hardcode document id value?

As workaround you can use webpart connection on the dispform.aspx of document library.